# Link to a button

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a 'tour' page that includes the dates of upcoming shows and a button that when clicks shows the number of tickets available and a 'buy' option. I want to link the 'buy' to ticketmaster, could someone help me with this please!?
Heres the code:

```
<td> <button  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="12 Available" data-content="Buy">Tickets</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Instead of using the button element, why not using the "a href" element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `data-html="true"`

```
<td> <button  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="12 Available" data-html="true" data-content="Buy this product click<a href='https://www.google.com'> here</a>">Tickets</button>
        </td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f9Lm0oew/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<td><a href="yourLink"> <button  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="12 Available" data-content="Buy">Tickets</button></a>
    </td>
```

Comment: Hi Abu Bin Oalid, I was hoping to have the link just for the 'buy'. So when the user click on the button it will display 2 popups, 1 the umber of tickets available and the other the option the 'buy' and when clicked it will open the link in a new tab to ticketmaster

Answer (score 0):

try with `onClick="window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';"` to the `<button>` element

```html
<td> <button  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="12 Available" data-content="Buy" onClick="window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';">Tickets</button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by that but you can make the button link to Ticketmaster this simple way:

```
<td> 
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" 
        data-trigger="focus" 
        title="12 Available" 
        data-content="Buy"
        onClick="()=>window.location.href = 'https://www.ticketmaster.com/'"
    >
        Tickets
    </button>
</td>
```

I added an onClick event that will link the button to Ticketmaster

Answer (score 0):

In order to let a button act like a link you need to add an event listener for the 'onclick' event of your button using Javascript, this is a simple way to do it:

(substiture the url with the one you need)

```
 <td> <button  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="12 Available" data-content="Buy" onclick="location.href = 'http:\\ticketmaster.com';">Tickets</button>
</td>
```

Good practice is inlcuding all event handling code in external javscript files, but for a one-shot applicataion this is good enough.

If you want further understanding you can find a lot of high quality educational material on web development in general on the MDN website(), this is a resource on events:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events